# How to use Ionic components in existing angular project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Intially I have an angular project where I have used Angular Material, later I have added the Ionic Framework by this process(https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/integrate-ionic-in-existing-angular-project/), but I am not able use Ionic components, even the console is not displaying any errors.

my app.module.ts

```
  import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

  imports[IonicModule]
```

HTML:

```
  <ion-badge color="primary">11</ion-badge>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use Ionic components in an existing Angular project.  Two easy steps:

1. Add `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` to your module (app.module.ts)

Like so:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas:      [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Add a link to the CDN in your index.html

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@5.0.0/dist/ionic.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include ionic library in angular by following command:

npm install @ionic/angular@latest --save

ref
https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cdn#ionic-angular